# Is legal to have a an argument void in Macro functions?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have code for the preprocessor below:

```
#define MYFUNC(void)  getFunc(void)
```

Is this legal in C?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is legal but it probably doesn't do what you expecting.

`#define MYFUNC(void)  getFunc(void)`

This defines a macro called `MYFUNC` that takes a single parameter, which in this case you have called `void`. This macro calls your function `getFunc` with the same parameter as passed to it.

In this case calling

`MYFUNC( "Hello" );`

will result in the same as

`getFunc( "Hello" );`

It is not clear if this is what you would be expecting. It would be a poor choice of parameter name to use as it is going to be confusing to any reader. While `void` is a keyword in C, it is nothing special in the C preprocessor.